# Dynamically combining loss functions in tensorflow keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function, multilabel-classification

I'm working on a multi-label classification problem where instead of each target index representing a distinct class, it represents some amount of time into the future. On top of wanting my predicted label to match the target label, I want an extra term to enforce some temporal aspect of the learning.

E.g.:

```py
y_true = [1., 1., 1., 0.]
y_pred = [0.75, 0.81, 0.93, 0.65]
```

Above, the truth label implies something occurring during the first three indices.

**I want to easily be able to mix and match loss functions.**

I have a couple custom loss functions for overall accuracy, each wrapped within functions for adjustable arguments:

```py
def weighted_binary_crossentropy(pos_weight=1):
    def weighted_binary_crossentropy_(Y_true, Y_pred):
        ...
        return tf.reduce_mean(loss, axis=-1)
    return weighted_binary_crossentropy_

def mean_squared_error(threshold=0.5):
    def mean_squared_error_(Y_true, Y_pred):
        ...
        return tf.reduce_mean(loss, axis=-1)
    return mean_squared_error
```

I also have a custom loss function to enforce the predicted label ending at the same time as the truth label (I haven't made use of the `threshold` argument here yet):

```py
def end_time_error(threshold=0.5):
    def end_time_error_(Y_true, Y_pred):
        _, n_times = K.int_shape(Y_true)
        weights = K.arange(1, n_times + 1, dtype=float)
        Y_true = tf.multiply(Y_true, weights)
        argmax_true = K.argmax(Y_true, axis=1)
        argmax_pred = K.argmax(Y_pred, axis=1)
        loss = tf.math.squared_difference(argmax_true, argmax_pred)
        return tf.reduce_mean(loss, axis=-1)
```

Sometimes I might want to combine `end_time_error` with `weighted_binary_crossentropy`, sometimes with `mean_squared_error`, and I have plenty of other loss functions to experiment with. I don't want to have to code a new combined loss function for each pair.

### Attempt at solution 1

I've tried making a meta-loss function that combines loss functions (globally defined in the same script).

```py
def combination_loss(loss_dict, combine='add', weights=[]):
    losses = []
    if not weights:
        weights = [1] * len(loss_dict)
    for (loss_func, loss_args), weight in zip(loss_dict.items(), weights):
        assert loss_func in globals().keys()
        loss_func = eval(loss_func)
        loss = loss_func(loss_args)
        losses.append(loss * weight)
    if combine == 'add':
        loss = sum(losses)
    elif combine == 'multiply':
        loss = np.prod(losses)
    return loss
```

To use this:

```py
loss_args = {'loss_dict':
                 {'weighted_binary_crossentropy': {'pos_weight': 1},
                  'end_time_error': {}},
             'combine': 'add',
             'weights': [0.75, 0.25]}
model.compile(loss=combination_loss(**loss_args), ...)
```

Error:

```py
  File "C:\...\losses.py", line 165, in combination_loss
    losses.append(loss * weight)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'function' and 'float'
```

I'm playing loose with functions, so I'm not surprised this failed. But I'm not sure how to get what I want.

How can I combine functions with weights in `combination_loss`?

Or should I be doing that directly in the `model.compile()` call using a lambda function?

### --EDIT

### Attempt at solution 2

Ditching `combination_loss`:

```py
losses = []
for loss_, loss_args_ in loss_args['loss_dict'].items():
    losses.append(get_loss(loss_)(**loss_args_))
loss = lambda y_true, y_pred: [l(y_true, y_pred) * w for l, w
                               in zip(losses, loss_args['weights'])]
model.compile(loss=loss, ...)
```

Error:

```py
  File "C:\...\losses.py", line 139, in end_time_error_
    weights = K.arange(1, n_times + 1, dtype=float)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Probably because `y_true, y_pred` won't work as arguments for wrapped loss functions.

Answer (score 1):

Let's simplify your use case for only two losses:

```
loss = alpha * loss1 + (1-alpha) * loss2
```

Then you can do:

```
def generate_loss(alpha):
    def combination_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        return alpha * loss1(y_true, y_pred) + (1-alpha) * loss2(y_true, y_pred)
    return combination_loss
```

Obviously, `loss1` and `loss2` would be your respective loss functions.
You can use this to generate different loss functions for different alphas:

```
alpha = 0.7
combination_loss = generate_loss(alpha)
model.compile(loss=combination_loss, ...)
```

If alpha is supposed to be static, you can also get rid of the outer function `generate_loss`.

Finally, you can also define this as a lambda function:

```
model.compile(loss=lambda y_true, y_pred: alpha * loss1(y_true, y_pred) + (1-alpha) * loss2(y_true, y_pred), ...)
```

I'm not sure where your bug is (I assume it's the `eval` but I can't debug it) but if you simplify it enough like this or use this as a working example to introduce your losses and weights, it should work.

Comment: This doesn't work because I have single output:
```python
ValueError: When passing a list as loss, it should have one entry per model outputs. The model has 1 outputs, but you passed loss=[<function weighted_binary_crossentropy.<locals>.weighted_binary_crossentropy_ at 0x000002218449CD38>, <function end_time_error.<locals>.end_time_error_ at 0x000002218449CDC8>]
```

Comment: I'll try something like in your edit, but I don't see where you're passing the additional loss function arguments, e.g. `pos_weight` for my `weighted_binary_crossentropy`.

Comment: You'll have to adapt my template (it's an MWE) to your use case. If you want to pass something to one of the "sub losses", you can add it to the outer function, e.g. `generate_loss(alpha, pos_weight)`.

Comment: Were you able to run your example above?